# Az CLI: Cannot run pipeline with runtime parameters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I'm trying to run a pipeline using AZ CLI. I have a simple pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: initials
  displayName: Initials
  type: string

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.initials }}
  displayName: Test
```

And I try to run it using:

```
az pipelines run --organization <my org> --project <my project> --name <pipeline> --branch <my branch> --debug --variables initials=maim
```

Then I end up with an error:

> ValidationResults":[{“result”:“error”,“message”:"A value for the parameter must be provided

Which is a bit odd since you can tell from the debug that the parameter is being set:

[image: Debug output]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It because you need to send `parameters` and you send `variables`.

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/972) it fixed in a new version:

1. Need to remove old package first:

```
az extension remove -n azure-devops
az extension add --source https://github.com/roshan-sy/release-repo/releases/download/1/azure_devops-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

2. Initial test looks good:

```
az login
az pipelines run --help
...
--parameters : Space separated "name=value" pairs for the parameters you would like to set.
...
az pipelines run --name "{pipeline.name}" --parameters Param1={Value1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for hours! Hoping for a new release soon

Comment: Yea, don't know for what they waiting... but this workaround works :)